# grep not working inside script when uses variables

Tags: shell

I have demo.csv file as

```
data1,text1,text01  
data2,text2,text02  
data3,text3,text03  
data4,text4,text04  
data5,text5,text05  
data6,text6,text06  
data7,text7,text07  
data8,text8,text08  
data9,text9,text09
```

I am writing a script demo.ksh for filter out data as

```
#!/bin/ksh
while [[ $1 = -* ]]
do
    case $1 in
        --data)
            shift
            ARGS="$ARGS -e \"$1\""
        ;;
        --excl)
            ARGS="-v $ARGS"
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
echo "grep $ARGS data.csv > test.txt"   
grep $ARGS data.csv > test.txt
```

demo.ksh and data.csv are in same dir.demo.ksh has +x permission.when I run demo.ksh as

```
demo.ksh --data data3
```

Output: 
`demo.ksh --data data3` <-- due to echo in script

test.txt is blank file (? Don't know why)
if I copy command which printed on console due to echo in demo.ksh, and paste directly on console and hit enter. it run fine and generate test.txt as

```
data3,text3,test03
```

why it is not working. am I missing something or executing grep in wrong manner inside shellscript

Comment: what if you add quotes around `--data` in your shell script? Also you are using $1 as arg, you should use $2 as arg.

Comment: it is fine I think. when I run output of echo "grep $ARGS data.csv > test.txt" from script, directly to cmd, its works fine.

Comment: You can't do it this way.   You are passing the literal argument `"data3"` to `grep` rather than the argument `data3`, and grep is trying to match the double quotes in the data.  The quotes here are doing nothing for you, and indeed if you called your script `demo.ksh --data 'foo bar'`, then grep would end up looking for the string `"foo` in a file named `bar"`!  It is equivalent to invoking `grep -e '"foo' 'bar"' data.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

The `-v` switch negates everything, not just the next string.  Duplicate `-v` switches act like a single `-v` switch.  Adding `-v` switches to `$ARG` can't make negation local to one string, unless by coincidence.

Since `$ARGS` can't contain a mix of positive regexes and negated ones, consider using two separate input files to hold the search strings:

```
#!/bin/ksh
pos=`mktemp`
neg=`mktemp`
while [ "$1" ]
do
    case $1 in
        --data)
            shift
            echo "$1" >> $pos
        ;;
        --excl)
            shift
            echo "$1" >> $neg
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
grep -f $pos data.csv | grep -v -f $neg > test.txt
rm $pos $neg
```

Note the syntax of `demo.ksh` has been left unchanged, but it's not very good syntax, since any search string or filename without a preceding `--excl` or `--data` would be lost.